# Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different. In an Animated View

Tags: javascript, react-native

As I understand this error can occur in a number of different use cases. Here is what happened in this use case

- An Animated View is being controlled by a `PanResponder` and this is reset at certain intervals to create an infinite scroll effect.
- Compiles and runs perfectly and functions as intended.
- Small gestures (almost like a tap) ie. pixel movements of about +- 4dx/ 4 dy the code crashes with the error in the title.

The error is thrown in the Child View of the `PanResponsder` with the mismatch resulting from the `translate: [{transform}]` I believe.

Why does the code function fine except for smaller gestures? What casuses the error?

[image: Error]

Comment: In my case, I was not updating an array state correctly, checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up resolving the issue.
In this case, it was specific to a `PanResponder`, but I believe this can occur in other situations as well, the error tracking should be similar. A **moveY** variable on the `PanResponder` went beyond a threshold set elsewhere. This resulted in `translateY` being set to **NaN** which threw the above error. This results in a mismatch in props.

1. If others experience this issue my advice would be to identify the specific component experiencing the mismatch. (In this case `PanResponder`)
2. Isolate the props (set defaults/ dummy values) and ensure that each prop is resolved correctly (especially in `Animated` `transform`: `translatex`/`translateY` )
3. Trace the prop responsible and adjust the logic specific to that prop to avoid **NaNs** and **undefined** being passed.

Answer (score 10):

I got this error when i mistakenly passed a closure as a second argument to AsyncStorage instead of the string literal i needed to store

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedIn', (err, result) => {
      console.log('I am logged In');
});
```

The correct thing to do is

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'my-jwt-token', (err, result) => {
      console.log('I am logged In');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar issue and solved it by changing easing value from elastic to other method. Yeah ! weird but solved the issue just incase it might be helpful to someone.

```
 Animated.timing(height, {
  toValue: 500,
  duration: 1500,
  easing: Easing.elastic,
}).start();
```

**TO**

```
 Animated.timing(height, {
  toValue: 500,
  duration: 1500,
  easing: Easing.linear,
}).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was passing an entire response object to an analytics tool, but it wasn't `JSON.stringify`-able.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if its relevent or not but in my case, this error was occuring when i was doing this in react native ->

`Alert.alert("Error", error, [ { text: "OK", }, ]);`

instead of this ->

`Alert.alert("Error", error.message, [ { text: "OK", }, ]);`

so that's means pass the correct data type and error will get resolve.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got this error when I was accidentally passing `NaN` to width property of a component.
So double check that all your data is in the expected/correct format at different stages of state updates.

Comment: `NaN` is the culprit.
In my case, I was passing `NaN` to a time picker that was expecting a `Date` ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was using `Easing.inOut` itself without passing another easing function inside, like `Easing.inOut(Easing.elastic(1))`. I thought Easing.inOut was an ease in itself but it actually just makes whatever easing function you pass into it symmetric. `Easing.in` and `Easing.out` similarly make whatever you pass into them run forwards or backwards. See https://reactnative.dev/docs/easing

Answer (score 0):

that error appeared to me when I passed a wrong type value as date to this peace of code

```
PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  channelId: 'channel-id', // (required) channelId, if the channel doesn't exist, notification will not trigger.
  title: 'My Notification Title', // (optional)
  message: 'My Notification Message', // (required)
  date: date, // in 60 secs
  allowWhileIdle: false, // (optional) set notification to work while on doze, default: false
  repeatTime: 1, // (optional) Increment of configured repeatType. Check 'Repeating Notifications' section for more info.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely about passing the wrong types into functions.

in my case, I was calling `setTimeout(ms, callback)` instead of `setTimeout(callback, ms)`.

I wish the error message said what line in my code caused the issue.
I spent 30 minutes tracking that down.